# Javascript setInterval method return always the same result from PHP method but I need changed data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So my problem is that I need to update some data from other site, and for calling that data I have php function where is the URL as parameter. ..So in JS I create a function that is in cycle with setInterval where I call that php function with URL parameter where are data stored, but it always return the same data..(data is actually playing track on stream, so data changed every +- 3 minutes) Data changes only on refresh page (f5) ..but I need update that data in background ..

this is the PHP function

```
function get_content($URL){
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  $data = str_replace(",,","},",$data);
  $data = str_replace("}}]}}","}]}}",$data);
  $data = str_replace("]}}","}]}}",$data);
  $data = str_replace(",}}","}}}",$data);
  $data = str_replace("}}]}}","}]}}",$data);
  return $data;
```

In js I call in setInterval cycle only console.log to show result of php function..

```
console.log(<?php echo (get_content("http://server1.internetoveradio.sk:8809/status-json.xsl"));?>["icestats"]["source"])
```

Comment: This isn't how PHP works; as a server-side language, any PHP is executed at page load before the HTML document is rendered. If you view the HTML source of this page, you'll see the `php echo` is no longer inside the `console.log`. Look into AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML) to retrieve content after a page is loaded: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

Comment: Have a look at your rendered source code and you'll see why this isn't working. You can't call a PHP function from Javascript -- all you can do is call a PHP script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yeah. The PHP only gets called once in this case, the one time you echo out the contents of get_content();

If you want to get the content over and over again, use XmlHTTPRequest to call a PHP file which then returns the the result of get_content();

jQuery implements ajax ( XmlHTTPRequest ) to do exactly that.

```
jQuery.ajax({
   url: "http://path.to/your_script.php",
   method: "get",
   complete: function( response ){
      console.log(response);
   }
});
```

edit:
Create a new .php file and paste this:

```
<?php

function get_content($URL){
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  $data = str_replace(",,","},",$data);
  $data = str_replace("}}]}}","}]}}",$data);
  $data = str_replace("]}}","}]}}",$data);
  $data = str_replace(",}}","}}}",$data);
  $data = str_replace("}}]}}","}]}}",$data);
  return $data;
}

echo get_content("http://server1.internetoveradio.sk:8809/status-json.xsl");
```

In your html, add this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
       url: "http://path.to/your_script.php",
       method: "get",
       complete: function( response ){
           console.log(response);
       }
    });
    });
</script>
```

This is the most rudimentory version, but it should point you in the right direction hopefully.

Comment: thanks ..but I don´t know how to rewrite that function into .php file ..to do that via AJAX ...I would like to do that this way ..but my skills in PHP is in the zero LEVEL ..and that PHP function was created by another programmer ..and I need to fix that problem :/